# How can I solve this first order non-linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

How can I solve this problem?,
$$\frac{y^2}{2} + 2 y e^x + (y + e^x) y'(x) = 0$$

I tried to convert to a exact differential equation by  multiply it by the integration factor $e^{\int \frac{M_{y}-N_{x}}{N} dx} = e^{\int x dx} = e^{x}$ where $M= \frac{y^2}{2} + 2 y e^x$ and $N= y + e^x$

I got that one families of solutions is
$$e^{x}y + e^{2x}+c$$
But I think I did it wrong.

Comment: What is the original equation

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Assuming that the equation you want to solve is
$$y^2+4ye^x+2(y+e^x)y'=0$$

put $$y=ze^x$$

it becomes

$$z^2+4z+2(z+1)(z'+z)=0$$
or

$$\frac{2(z+1)}{z^2+2z}z'=-3$$
and
$$(\frac 1z+\frac{1}{z+2})z'=-3$$

thus
$$z(z+2)=\lambda.e^{-3x}=(z+1)^2-1$$

Comment: When  you substitute $y= e^{z}$ you obtain $z^{2}e^{2x}+4ze^{2x}+2(ze^{x}+e^{x})(z'e^{x}+ze^{x})=0$  it becomes $z^{2}e^{x}+4xe^{x}+2(z+1)(z'+z))=0$, doesn't it?

Comment: No, i made the substitution $ y = z e^x $ not $ y=e^z$.

Comment: Sorry, I did  a mistake, is $y= ze^{x}$ anyway, I think the substitution is wrong

Comment: @Mari You simplify by $ e^{2x}$.